# Generate 1d array form txt file using python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am new in python.For my collage project in need to developed some program,for data analysis I work with large numbers of array, the value of those array are taken from text file In txt file the value are given below

> ```
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0,0,0
> 0,0,0,0,0,0
> 0,0
> 0,0,0
> ```

I want to convert in a 1 dimensional array like
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

How I do that. Thank you

I get some help full code but that not work, I get some error that I cant recognized

```
path2='page_2.txt'
input2 = np.array(np.loadtxt(path2, dtype='i', delimiter=','))
```

Error:

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-139-8836e57e833d> in <module>
>       5 
>       6 path2='page_2.txt'
> ----> 7 input2 = np.array(np.loadtxt(path2, dtype='i', delimiter=','))
>       8 
>       9 path3='page_4.txt'
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname,
> dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack,
> ndmin, encoding)    1099         # converting the data    1100        
> X = None
> -> 1101 for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):1102 if X is None:1103 X = np.array(x, dtype) 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in
> read_data(chunk_size)    1023                 line_num = i + skiprows
> + 1 1024 raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
> -> 1025 % line_num)1026 1027# Convert each value according to its column and store
> ```
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that line 4 (i.e. 0,0,0) has three columns as opposed to the first three lines.

What you could do instead is to concatenate all the lines and transform it into an array:

```
with open(path2) as f:
    str_arr = ','.join([l.strip() for l in f])

int_arr = np.asarray(str_arr.split(','), dtype=int)

print(int_arr)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all the elements from the whole file in a single array.

That could be done like this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    numbers = [
        e
        for line in f
        for e in line.strip().split(',')]

int_arr = np.asarray(numbers, dtype=int)
```

Afterward we have:

```
>>> print(int_arr)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```